# How to remotely debug console commands in Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging, symfony-3.1

**Problem**

I want to debug Symfony console commands on a remote VM server. I can get it to work to debug the `bin/console` script and all related method calls in the `\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application` but as soon as it calls the execute method of the specific command (in `symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:256`) the debugger mapping somehow looses the mapping and does not work anymore.  I can not make it break at any breakpoints I set at the specific command.

**Setup**

On the VM I have the following php settings:

```
# /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
```

Before starting the debug session I create a SSH tunnel with

```
ssh -nNT -R 9000:localhost:9000 joerg@sa-platform.dev-vm
```

In PhpStorm I have the deployment configured using `SFTP` and set the PHP CLI interpreter to the remote php cli version.

I activate the "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections". The first time the connection was made, the server debug connection was created and I added the mapping for the root dir of the project:

[image: PHP Server Config]

On my local machine the IP `192.168.56.57` is mapped to the domain `sa-platform.dev-vm` in `/etc/hosts`.

When I call my command on the VM `bin/console sa:events:group` I get the connection in PhpStorm stopping at the first line of the related console script.

[image: debug connection breaking at first line of console script]

And I can debug until the point where the execute function of my command is called:

[image: debug console application until command execute function is called]

But after that no chance to debug my command.

I have tried setting the PHP server mapping in PhpStorm directly to the command files, which did not work.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
As suggested I have added the log file and set the accept external debug connections to 5 in PhpStorm.

I have no clue about the log, but maybe someone does?

The [complete log of one session can be found here](https://pastebin.com/8rgUyshE). The last entries look like this:

```
<- context_get -i 23 -d 0 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="23" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_ENV" fullname="$_ENV" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_FILES" fullname="$_FILES" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_GET" fullname="$_GET" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_POST" fullname="$_POST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_REQUEST" fullname="$_REQUEST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_SERVER" fullname="$_SERVER" type="array" children="1" numchildren="27" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="COMP_WORDBREAKS" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;COMP_WORDBREAKS&#39;]" type="string" size="12" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[IAkKIic+PDt8Jig6]]></property><property name="TERM" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;TERM&#39;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[eHRlcm0tMjU2Y29sb3I=]]></property><property name="SHELL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SHELL&#39;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2Jpbi9iYXNo]]></property><property name="SSH_CLIENT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SSH_CLIENT&#39;]" type="string" size="21" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTkyLjE2OC41Ni4xIDUxODQ2IDIy]]></property><property name="OLDPWD" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;OLDPWD&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2hvbWUvam9lcmc=]]></property><property name="SSH_TTY" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SSH_TTY&#39;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2Rldi9wdHMvMA==]]></property><property name="USER" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;USER&#39;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[am9lcmc=]]></property><property name="LS_COLORS" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;LS_COLORS&#39;]" type="string" size="1422" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></property><property name="MAIL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;MAIL&#39;]" type="string" size="15" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci9tYWlsL2pvZXJn]]></property><property name="PATH" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;PATH&#39;]" type="string" size="56" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Vzci9sb2NhbC9iaW46L3Vzci9iaW46L2JpbjovdXNyL2xvY2FsL2dhbWVzOi91c3IvZ2FtZXM=]]></property><property name="PWD" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;PWD&#39;]" type="string" size="20" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3Zhci93d3cvc2EtcGxhdGZvcm0=]]></property><property name="LANG" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;LANG&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZGVfREUuVVRGLTg=]]></property><property name="GCC_COLORS" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;GCC_COLORS&#39;]" type="string" size="66" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZXJyb3I9MDE7MzE6d2FybmluZz0wMTszNTpub3RlPTAxOzM2OmNhcmV0PTAxOzMyOmxvY3VzPTAxOnF1b3RlPTAx]]></property><property name="SHLVL" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SHLVL&#39;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MQ==]]></property><property name="HOME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;HOME&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L2hvbWUvam9lcmc=]]></property><property name="LOGNAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;LOGNAME&#39;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[am9lcmc=]]></property><property name="SSH_CONNECTION" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SSH_CONNECTION&#39;]" type="string" size="35" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTkyLjE2OC41Ni4xIDUxODQ2IDE5Mi4xNjguNTYuNTcgMjI=]]></property><property name="_" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;_&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmluL2NvbnNvbGU=]]></property><property name="PHP_SELF" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;PHP_SELF&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmluL2NvbnNvbGU=]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_NAME&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmluL2NvbnNvbGU=]]></property><property name="SCRIPT_FILENAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;SCRIPT_FILENAME&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmluL2NvbnNvbGU=]]></property><property name="PATH_TRANSLATED" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;PATH_TRANSLATED&#39;]" type="string" size="11" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmluL2NvbnNvbGU=]]></property><property name="DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;DOCUMENT_ROOT&#39;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT&#39;]" type="float"><![CDATA[1496314052.1787]]></property><property name="REQUEST_TIME" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;REQUEST_TIME&#39;]" type="int"><![CDATA[1496314052]]></property><property name="argv" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;argv&#39;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="2"></property><property name="argc" fullname="$_SERVER[&#39;argc&#39;]" type="int"><![CDATA[2]]></property></property><property name="$GLOBALS" fullname="$GLOBALS" type="array" children="1" numchildren="17" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="_GET" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_GET&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_POST" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_POST&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_COOKIE" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_COOKIE&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_FILES" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_FILES&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="argv" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;argv&#39;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="2"></property><property name="argc" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;argc&#39;]" type="int"><![CDATA[2]]></property><property name="_ENV" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_ENV&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_REQUEST" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_REQUEST&#39;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_SERVER" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;_SERVER&#39;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="27"></property><property name="GLOBALS" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;GLOBALS&#39;]" type="array" children="1" recursive="1"></property><property name="__composer_autoload_files" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;__composer_autoload_files&#39;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="9"></property><property name="loader" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;loader&#39;]" type="object" classname="Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader" children="1" numchildren="9"></property><property name="input" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;input&#39;]" type="object" classname="Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput" children="1" numchildren="6"></property><property name="env" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;env&#39;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZGV2]]></property><property name="debug" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;debug&#39;]" type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property><property name="kernel" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;kernel&#39;]" type="object" classname="AppKernel" children="1" numchildren="10"></property><property name="application" fullname="$GLOBALS[&#39;application&#39;]" type="object" classname="Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application" children="1" numchildren="14"></property></property></response>

<- context_get -i 24 -d 0 -c 2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="24" context="2"><property name="RANDOM_COMPAT_READ_BUFFER" fullname="RANDOM_COMPAT_READ_BUFFER" type="int" facet="constant"><![CDATA[8]]></property></response>

<- run -i 25
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="25" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- run -i 26
Log closed at 2017-06-01 10:48:01
```

Comment: 1) Collect xdebug log to see what's happening there 2) Since I'm not familiar with how Symfony tasks are actually run ... maybe they run as separate process (which means separate debug session)? If so -- you may need to increase max session limit from default 1 to 5 (for example) in PhpStorm settings. 3) Since it's a CLI and you have SSH access - try launching whole debug directly from IDE https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: 1) I can not really figure out what the log says me. 2) ok, raised to 5, was set to 2 before, no change, 3) I launched the remote debug from the ide via a `PHP Remote Debug` configuration. No change, same behaviour.

Comment: 1) Maybe it tries to execute the code that it cannot find the mapping for? Any symbolic links in the project on remote system? try removing all your breakpoints and put only `xdebug_break();` in the file where you wish to break (where it cannot debug) -- any difference? what xdebug log says for such scenario. 2) It was not needed then -- 2 was enough for your case 3) if it's a CLI script then you should use ordinary "PHP Script" type of config but use Remote PHP Interpreter (which you have to set in your PhpStorm).

Comment: no symlinks used and it worked for another symfony core command. That and another thinking about the mapping I deployed all code again to the vm which solves the problem. So it seems like the mapping could not be done, because my local command was different from the one on the vm. Thanks for you help. How should I proceed with this question? Give the answer myself and mark it as solution?

Comment: yes, that would be the best case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, my local version of the `SaEventsGroupCommand` I was trying to debug was different from the version on the VM. After checking the mapping and trying all suggestions from @LazyOne I did a deployment form my local machine to the VM for the commands bundle. And suprise after that it worked and the debugger was breaking at my break points as intended.

So conclusion if anyone comes across a similar problem. Make sure you have deployed all your code manually to the remote server or your automatically deployment is set to deploy external changes (e.g. different git branches) to the server.